# Hashta Ba'agala

Tags: tefilla, torah-service, language, aramaic

There have been questions about the use of [Aramaic](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65188/how-holy-is-aramaic) as a [language](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17557/reasons-for-the-laws-of-the-prayers-in-aramaic) of [prayer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13925/aramaic-sections-of-davening-in-hebrew), in whole or in [part](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13714/why-do-we-still-say-sections-of-davening-in-aramaic), and even a question about the possible appearance of a [single](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33493/solitary-aramaic-word-in-al-hanissim) Aramaic word in an otherwise Hebrew prayer, or what [laws](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33491/source-for-saying-aramaic-parts-of-davening-quietly) are invoked but I am wondering about words I haven't seen addressed (if I missed it, apologies).

In two separate prayers -- the prayer for [healing](http://www.egabbai.com/Docs/Oleh/ill_one2.pdf) (in Shacharis for shabbos) and the paragraph of [Acheinu](http://www.hebrewsongs.com/?song=acheinu) which we say after leining, a prayer predominantly in Hebrew is closed with "[Hashta](http://aramaicandbiblicalhebrew.blogspot.com/2013/04/hei-ha-chi-cha.html) [Ba'agala](https://books.google.com/books?id=VhU9lLHV0eAC&pg=PA422&lpg=PA422&dq=agala%20aramaic&source=bl&ots=iJoZD4xOg9&sig=SQ-kma7A7mB6TJY3LiSLMykzTg0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwict6WBz9zMAhWGyj4KHdtsCqAQ6AEIMjAE#v=onepage&q=agala%20aramaic&f=false)" which is in Aramaic [I don't know if "[kariv](http://ohr.edu/explore_judaism/ask_the_rabbi/ask_the_rabbi/659)" is Aramaic or not so I excluded it from this question.]

Why do the prayers switch for those 2 (approx) words from Hebrew to Aramaic?

Comment: A hunch that the answer shown in http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13737/5275 may have something to do with it, esp. regarding both prayers for the ill as well as "Acheinu" which is a prayer for redeeming the prisoners. I can't, offhand, state why, but I'm thinking that maybe there is an angel that wants to harm both these type of people? I like Art Scroll siddur for many things, but, it does have many inconsistencies. So, just because the Mi Shebrach L'cholim isn't in the weekday section doesn't mean it's not said. In my shul, I say it every time the Torah is read. (It's my "assignment".)

Comment: I would say that Uvizman Kariv (Bechayechon... ...Baagala Uvizman Kariv, Veimru Amen) is also Aramaic.  Great Q, BTW, +1.

Comment: Also, the words are found in an aramaic tefillah at the end of selichos.

Comment: famously, hebrew is a fluid language. perhaps at the time these prayers were minted these words were being borrowed and used as part of hebrew

Comment: השתא is also Aramaic

Answer (score 3):

This answer is complete speculation. It is not sourced from anywhere, just my own original thoughts and pshat (understanding).

If I'm not mistaken, at the time that the Nusach (formulation) of our prayers were made, the spoken language of the people was Aramaic, not Hebrew. Maybe the author of those prayers wanted those words to be in the peoples' spoken language in order that those words should be spoken out more authentically and passionately.

Imagine a (rude) child passionately asking his mother for something and screaming: "I want it ***now***!"

Imagine that same child being forced to say that same line in a foreign language. He would most likely be forced to say it less authentically and passionately.

We should see the healing of all sick people and Greatness of Hashems name spread throughout the land ***Hastah Ba'agallah!!***